# Yii2 node how get redis session key by user id

Tags: node.js, redis, yii2

I'm using [Yii-2-real-time-chat-app-with-nodejs-socketio-and-redisio](https://www.my-yii.com/learn/view-episode/yii-2-real-time-chat-app-with-nodejs-socketio-and-redisio).
I need to send notification to a specific user want to use key redis
How get key redis session by user id?

Trying in yii\redis\Session

```
    protected function calculateKey($id)
        {
            return $this->keyPrefix ."".$_SESSION['__id']."".               
            md5(json_encode([__CLASS__, $id]));
        }
```

but authorization not working

Answer (score 0):

session should be available as:

```
Yii::$app->session->get('id')
```

redis should be accessible as:

```
Yii::$app->redis->get('key');
```

Session and Redis should be defined as  components in config

Notify user as:

```
 return Yii::$app->redis->executeCommand('PUBLISH', [
        'channel' => 'notification_user_'<THERE_WILL_BE_USER_IDENTIFIER>,
        'message' => Json::encode(['name' => $name, 'message' => $message])
    ]);
```

Listen on client as:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890');

socket.on('notification_user_<THERE_WILL_BE_SAME_USER_IDENTIFIER>', function (data) {

    var message = JSON.parse(data);

    $( "#notifications" ).prepend( "<p><strong>" + message.name + "</strong>: " + message.message + "</p>" );

});
```

});

I think this should work